# How SQL server decides the priority of a request?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking, database-deadlocks

Lets say there are 3 users A,B,C  hitting to the db and runs a update query at the **same** point of time(Not even a milisecond diff).

**Example Scenario**:
Lets say we have a ref_Product_qty table which stores the product id and quantiy available in the warehouse.

Now we have a "Add to Cart" button on our site. When thousand of user will hit this button at the same time there is a sure possibility of overlapping and we have this query running behind.

```
if (qty > 0) {
UPDATE  ref_Product_qry
SET qty = qty-1
WHERE   productid = 12345
}
```

Now which user out of A/B/C will get the highest priority?

We can have many other similar kind of scenarios.

I have gone through both optimistic and pessimistic locking(Isolation levels) , But still I do not have the clear idea, How SQL Server prioritises the update/write request if they came at same time.

I know this is a very basic question , but i did not get a clear idea even after reading many blogs.Please help.

Comment: I'm afraid that all the answers you'll get will paraphrase the blogs you already read, especially because we don't know what you read and didn't understand.

Comment: @X.L.Ant: I just want to know if two requests comes at exactly same point of time to SQL server then how it prioritises the request ?I know we can use transactions , and set the isolation level to serialization , so that one request will wait for the other to complete. But which request will execute and which will wait ,  How it decides if both came at same time?

Comment: @pala_: So as per you 2 request can not hit to db server exactly at same point of time.

Comment: yes thats my understanding (sorry, deleted comment for some reason). the connection handler is a single threaded entity, so connections are processed one at a time. they are handed off to worker threads after that but for all intents and purposes, there is no 'exact same time'

Comment: Instead of separately checking the quantity and then running the update, apply a `WHERE` clause, e.g. `WHERE productId = 12345 and qty > 1` and then check the number of rows affected. If you updated 0 rows then either the product doesn't exist or the qty is zero and that user lost. If the row count is 1, then that user won. Keep it simple.

Comment: "Same time" is impossible, but anyway, the actual question seems to be how to handle concurrency. There are many many questions (and answers) on that topic. This question lacks detail to answer it for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I know this has been quite some time but maybe this could help out people with similar questions.
Now in the comments you Stated:

> I just want to know if two requests comes at exactly same point of
> time to SQL server then how it prioritises the request ?I know we can
> use transactions , and set the isolation level to serialization , so
> that one request will wait for the other to complete. But which
> request will execute and which will wait , How it decides if both came
> at same time?

So first things first: There is no real way to explain which User the System will pick. To put it very simply the System runs through an algorithm considering complexety, duration etc. and then "just picks one". So in this case if the time of execution is to be ignored, the choice will pretty much seem random too us. But there were some questions in your comment Id like to answere using a different example if I may. Make sure to run those sessions in two different querys windows.

Session One:

```
BEGIN TRAN SessionOne;

UPDATE dbo.FirstTableForViewTest
SET ColB = 'B'
WHERE FTFVTID = 1;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

UPDATE dbo.SecondTableForViewTest
SET ColF = 'F'
WHERE STFVTID = 1;

COMMIT TRAN SessionOne;
```

Session Two:

```
BEGIN TRAN SessionTwo;

UPDATE dbo.SecondTableForViewTest
SET ColF = 'F'
WHERE STFVTID = 1;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

UPDATE dbo.FirstTableForViewTest
SET ColB = 'B'
WHERE FTFVTID = 1;

COMMIT TRAN SessionTwo;
```

The Delay is just for you to make it easier to run theese close to one another.
Now even in this case and even if you Start one of the Session before the other, its not alawys going to be the same Session comming out on top.
But what happens here? Ok so in this case SessionOne will aquire a lock on the Row in the first table where the ID is 1, and SessionTwo will do the same thing for the second table. after both of them have waited they will try to get a lock on the row that is already locked by the other session. They will attempt to wait until the lock is released and they cajn procced. However the System recongnises that both Sessions/Transactions block oneanother and that a deadlock is occurring. Now the System will run its algorithm to pick something called a "Deadlock Victim". That victim is hte Transaction choosen by the system to be rolled back/terminated, thereby releasing any locks it held, resulting in the other Transaction being able to proceed.
But now lets say we really really want SessionTwo to not be terminated when it gets into a deadlock with SessionOne.
Then we make a slight Change

Session One:

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY NORMAL
BEGIN TRAN SessionOne;

UPDATE dbo.FirstTableForViewTest
SET ColB = 'B'
WHERE FTFVTID = 1;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

UPDATE dbo.SecondTableForViewTest
SET ColF = 'F'
WHERE STFVTID = 1;

COMMIT TRAN SessionOne;
```

Session Two:

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH
BEGIN TRAN SessionTwo;

UPDATE dbo.SecondTableForViewTest
SET ColF = 'F'
WHERE STFVTID = 1;

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

UPDATE dbo.FirstTableForViewTest
SET ColB = 'B'
WHERE FTFVTID = 1;

COMMIT TRAN SessionTwo;
```

The Value you can use for priorities can be different then just LOW, NORMAL, HIGH. You can use numbers. LOW = -5, NORMAL = 0, HIGH = 5. The range at your disposal is -10 to 10.

So to sum up an answere your general question: If you have multiple Querys/Transactions running at the same time doing incredably similar things, then you cant predict which one will run first.
I hope this was at least slightly helpfull, and Im sorry if it wasnt.