# At the exact same time if 2 transactions try to update the same row of the same table.How the transaction management system manages here?

Tags: sql-server

This is the question I have been asked in an interview. I tried to give the answer based on locking. Any of the one transaction will acquire exclusive lock but then the quetion is if both the transaction has started at the exact same time then how SQL server will decide which trnasaction will get the exclusive lock first. And what if there are mutiple transcation that get started at the same time to update the same row of same table, how it will be handled by MS SQL server?

Comment: Seems to me you need to do a bit of research on locking. This is a pretty big topic that has been covered many many times already.

Answer (score 1):

One of the transaction will be granted the Xclusive lock, the other transactions will wait for the lock to be released.

Comment: Which transaction will be granted the exclusive lock, and how SQL server will decide this ?

Comment: The connection handler is single threaded, so there cannot be a "same time" for two transactions to start, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343800/how-sql-server-decides-the-priority-of-a-request

Comment: Before the exclusive lock is taken there are intent locks. The intent locks combined with shared locks pretty much manage the queue when there are exclusive locks being taken. Kalen Delaney has some excellent descriptions in her various books as to how this is done. Please read her stuff for a more accurate and correct description on how SQL Server manages locking.